# AWS copy command does not work in EC2 instance with python psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

When I'm using SQL workbench, the AWS copy command works well.
The purpose is to copy S3 data to Redshift table.
Here's the copy command I'm using:

```
copy oao_features_usbank_v2 from 's3://my_bucket/test_data.csv' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/my_role' CSV IGNOREHEADER 1 MAXERROR 10 DELIMITER as '|';
```

Then when using python `psycopg2`. I have tried multiple connection methods, none of them work. Such as:

```
conn_string = 'postgresql://username:pwd@host:port/db'
copy_query = 'copy oao_features_usbank_v2 from 's3://my_bucket/test_data.csv' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/my_role' CSV IGNOREHEADER 1 MAXERROR 10 DELIMITER as '|';'

with psycopg2.connect(conn_string) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(copy_query)
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import psycopg2
​
db = "your_database"
host = "redshift_end_point"
port = "5439"
user = "your_user_here"
pwd = "your_password_here"
connstr = "dbname=%s host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s" % (db, host, port, user, pwd)
​
con = psycopg2.connect(connstr)
```

The Redshift end point can be found in the AWS console. It will look something like:

```
clustername.sofhsdl34534.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com
```

Your EC2 instance should also have a Security Group attached that allows connecting to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting your copy_query into multiple line string like below:
copy_query = """copy oao_features_usbank_v2 from 's3://my_bucket/test_data.csv' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/my_role' CSV IGNOREHEADER 1 MAXERROR 10 DELIMITER as '|';' """

So that python code will take all the string inside of three quotes as your copy command